# Issue with exact dependencies in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Error:

Because
built_value_generator >=8.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on built_value ^8.0.0-nullsafety.0
flutter_app depends on built_value ^7.1.0, built_value_generator >=8.0.0-nullsafety.0 is forbidden.

So, because flutter_app depends on built_value_generator ^8.0.0-nullsafety.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_app depends on built_value_generator ^8.0.0-nullsafety.0, version solving failed.)

If I delete the following, then the app compiles with no issues.

> built_value_generator: ^8.0.0-nullsafety.0

My dependencies are below

```
    version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:   sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
       flutter:
        sdk: flutter
       chopper: ^2.4.1
       provider: ^3.0.0+1 
       connectivity: ^0.4.3+2 
       built_value: ^7.1.0
    
    cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
    
    dev_dependencies:
       flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
       chopper_generator: ^2.3.4
    
      built_value_generator: ^8.0.0-nullsafety.0
      build_runner:
    

    flutter:
       uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Use the null-safety version for built_value too!

Comment: @TirthPatel If u mean use **built_value: ^7.1.0-nullsafety.0** - it doesn't word ass well.

Comment: Latest null safety version of built_value is 8.0.0-nullsafety.0

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/built_value/versions#prerelease

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in deppendency versions mismatching, it is obviously described in warning message. So don't use nullsafety version of `built_value_generator`, use latest non-nullsafety version. Or use nullsafety version of `built_value`.

Also it is recommended to read about dart dependencies https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies.

It is also recommended to set minimum version  of dart SDK to 2.7 not.2.1.

Comment: I added nullsafety cause i found it on some sources. But thing is app doesnt want to compile even with built_value_generator: ^7.1.0 ( i mean exactly same version).

Comment: So don't use nullsafety version.

Comment: Nullsafety can be used from dart 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'any' to resolve the issue

```
built_value_generator: any
```